# Resource Bundle Deleted in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, resourcebundle

I am using ResourceBundle class in a project only to retrieve paths to some files.
The file it uses its called "properties.properties" and i placed it in the "bin" folder of an eclipse project.

The code looks like this:

```
String filename = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties").getString(key);
```

From time to time, the file "properties.properties" dissappears from the "bin" folder. What might be the cause?

Comment: You may be running "clean" on a project. bin is not a place to keep sources

Comment: please change location of property file, it should not be inside bin directory.whenever you clean project it flush bin directory.

Comment: I managed to clean my project, but the file still hasn't disappeared. It only deleted the folders and .class files in the bin folder. I see your point though. I'll move it to a different folder and if it disappears again ill be back.

Comment: Put it into (one of) the source folder, then eclipse will copy it to the bin folder automatically.